# Ship is not floating in Blender

Tags: animation, cycles-render-engine

I tried to make scene with floating container ship with [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xMDW0lWM130&t=14s) tutorial
But whenever I use copy rotation the ship is behaving very weird. Can You help me?
My Blend File is [here](https://we.tl/t-sbPvDK5gFX)

Answer (score 3):

If you select your ship and look at its rotation:

[image: rotation]

I suppose you imported your ship from elsewhere, and whoever made that ship model used a software with a Yup coordinates system. So when Blender imported it, it rotated your model of 90° to make sure that the model's "original"  upside was preserved. But because the Copy Rotation constraint uses the object's original rotation, it causes you issues.

To fix it:

1. Remove your constraint temporarily by clicking its cross icon
2. Select your ship in Object mode and hit <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> > *Apply Rotation*
3. Add your constraint again